# Linear Operator over the space of functions whose first derivative is continuous.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, differential-operators

I came across a question regarding Linear transformation stating as follows:

Let $V$ denotes the space of all real valued functions whose first derivative is continuous. And $T$ is the linear operator over V defined as follows: $$T(f) = f'(x) + \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$$

I couldn't find the $Ker(T)$ and also $f \in V$ the satisfies $T(f) = f$.

My thought on the first place where as follows:

The only solution for the $null$ $space$ is $0$ since we want $f'(x) + F(x) = 0$, $F(x)$ being the antiderivative, Therefore $F''(x) + f(x) = 0$ and we aren't sure regarding $F''(x)$ exists unless it's $0$

And for $T(f) = f$, I guess the only possible solution would rather be only $f = 0$ but don't know how to construct a solution for that.

Comment: $T$ is a linear operator over $V $ means $T$ is from $V $ to $V $, right? If that's the case, you may need to restrict your domain.

Comment: I mean by linear operator, a linear transformation from V to V, what do you mean by restricting the domain?

Comment: So $Tf$ lies in $V$ and therefore should have a continuous first derivative. But as you noted above, not every $f $ has a second derivative. So you have to restrict your $T $ to those functions that have continuous second derivative as well. (But, as it is a linear algebra question, probably you can ignore all these and assume that $Tf\in V $ for all $f\in V $. Then $f''+f=0$.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but  regardless the way I'm following to find the Ker(T) would that mean that Ker(T) = {0} ?